# This perl code is not working, what mistake am I making?

Tags: perl

Can anyone tell me why the below code is showing an error.I am working on perl. I started 
working on perl right from 5 minutes back.This is my first program in perl.But its saying syntax error unexpected ';' I wrote the code exactly what given in book.but whats the problem ?where does the error lieing?

```
###!/cygdrive/c/dynasty/gcc/bin

$in =  <<STDIN>> ;

print ($in) ;
```

and could you suggest me any good pdfs for perl script thank you.

Comment: why the <STDIN> not printing and the # symbol in the start line?

Comment: You didn’t actually type that, since that won’t even compile: `Can't find string terminator "STDIN" anywhere before EOF` happens if you attempt to use `<<STDIN>>` anywhere.  What does your code actually look like?

Comment: @tchrist: I was guessing some earlier version printed the different error;  now that I think of it, I don't see how that's possible.  I think he did actually type that but it is a shell error he's reporting.

Comment: Maybe that's what his code actually looks like, but his error is coming from something other than perl. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
$in = <STDIN>;
print ($in);
```

Also, [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) is an excellent tutorial.

Comment: @cody - If you had `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script, it would have caught this issue for you.

Comment: @Mark Mann: no, it wouldn't have.  good advice anyway, though.

Answer (score 5):

You should have `<STDIN>` instead of `<<STDIN>>`.  The latter is being parsed as a heredoc (`<<STDIN`) as the left operand of a right-shift operation (`>>`), but there's no right operand for the right-shift, hence the `unexpected ;` error.

Update: except that perl first complains about not finding the STDIN indicating the end of the heredoc.  It seems the shell is executing the code instead of perl, and the `>>` is a redirect, not a right-shift.  Otherwise, the above still applies.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to read from the STDIN file glob is:

```
my $in = <STDIN>;
```

Note - only **one** set of angle brackets.

Answer (score 2):

**The # line**

This line tells the machine what to do with the file when it is executed (ie it tells it to run the file through Perl).

**STDIN**

It should be: `my $in = <STDIN>;`

Comment: "my" means that you declare a new local variable here

Comment: @cody: you need to stop trying to write code and read through a beginning introduction to perl, such as Learning Perl.