# Why doesn't Perl warn for the redeclaration of a my() variable in the same scope?

Tags: perl, syntax-error

```
use strict;

my $world ="52";

my $in = "42" ;

my $world="42";

my $out = "good" ."good";

chop($out);

print $out;
```

Do not worry about the code.The question is that I used `my $world` in two different lines but compiler didn't give any error but if we consider C language's syntax then we will get the error because of the redeclaration of variable. Why don't perl gives any error for redeclaration. I have one more question: What is the size of a scalar variable ?

Comment: Avoid `chop`, use `chomp` instead.  `chop` always removes the last character, `chomp` removes the line ending (as defined by the `$/`).  If the current line ending is CRLF, `chop` will leave you with a CR left in your string.

Comment: Well, avoid `chop` if you only want to remove a line ending. If you want to remove the last character no matter what it is, `chop` is still the tool to use.

Comment: If you have a completely separate question about the size of a variable, make a separate post.

Comment: It sounds like you need to start from the beginning of Perl. [Learning Perl, 6th Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452/) just came out this week :)

Comment: btw redeclaration is **not** a syntax error! rather it is a logical/semantic error in C

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1/ Variable redeclaration is not an error. Had you included "use warnings" then you would get a warning.

2/ By "size of scalar variable" do you mean the amount of data that it can store? If that's the case, Perl imposes no arbitrary limits.

You seem to be posting a lot of rather simple questions very quickly. Have you considered reading ["Learning Perl"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452)?

Comment: not yet sir Im just learning from the internet and now im at if else statements i just got a doubt becuase in c int takes 2 bytes and char 1 byte so similarly i wanted to know is there any size for scalar variable in perl if there is no size then the programs gets much tougher right

Comment: Learning from the internet can be a dangerous idea. There are a large number of inaccurate and outdated tutorials out there. I hope you started from http://learn.perl.org/.

Answer (score 5):

> The question is my $world i used it in two different lines but compiler said no error but to the c we get error as redclaration of variable but why not in perl.

Simply because Perl isn't C, and redefining a variable isn't an error condition.

It can be a cause of unexpected behaviour though and would be picked up if you had `use warnings;` (as has been [suggested to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519183/this-code-its-aint-working/6519245#6519245)).

> What is the size of scalar variable ? is there any size?

Define 'size'. Bytes? Characters? Something else? You might be looking for [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because Perl likes to be robust. If you had `warnings` turned on, you would have heard about it.

```
"my" variable $world masks earlier declaration in same scope at - line 7.
```

Although USUW (`use strict; use warnings;`) is a good development practice, so *would* be using [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie)--*if* autodie worried about syntax warnings. But the following, concept is roughly the same, to make sure that you're not avoiding any warnings.

```
BEGIN { $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die @_; }; }
```

The above code creates a signal handler for warnings that just dies instead. However, I think this is better for a beginner:

```
BEGIN {
    $SIG{__WARN__} 
        = sub { 
            eval { 
                # take me out of the chain, to avoid recursion
                delete $SIG{__WARN__};
                # diag will install the warn handler we want to use.    
                eval 'use diagnostics;';  
                $SIG{__WARN__}->( @_ ); # invoke that handler
            };
            exit 1; # exit regardless of errors that might have cropped up.
        }; 
}
```

Anywhere you want, you can tell perl that you are not interested in changing your code to issue a particular category of warnings (and `diagnostics` will tell you the category!) and if you explicitly tell perl `no warnings 'misc'`, not only will it not warn you, but it will also not fire off the warning handler, which kills the program.

This will give you a more c-like feel--except that c has warnings too (so you could implement a lexical counter as well...oh well.)

Comment: Why should you `use English` for `$EVAL_ERROR`, which you don't use, but leave `@_` in there instead of `@ARGS` :)?

Comment: @brian d foy: [Damion's reasons in PBP](http://books.google.com/books?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&pg=PT103&dq=%22Perl+Best+Practices%22+English+ARG&hl=en&ei=w2ELTvqZMuuOsAKgh_SnAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false): The '_' variables are not obscure, kinda like `$()` in jQuery.

Comment: But you're not using `$EVAL_ERROR`. PBP is great, but some of its advice is outdated, overkill or suspect. I'd put this one in overkill. IMO I'd count @_, $@, $!, $_ and $1 together in the family of "seen often enough that they're not obscure" symbolic variables.  If you don't know what $@ is you're not going to be able to read other people's Perl.

Comment: @Schwern, ah the use is a holdover from an earlier generation of code, where I was (at the end of the eval). I think the principle in PBP is sound and you have to draw a line somewhere. And 3 After fitful attempts to use msx flags on *every* regex, I finally gave that up.